# Double for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, twitter

I am scraping twitter trending topics and want to do three separate scrapes:

1.) By Geo 
2.) With Hashtags
3.) Without Hashtags

So i ostensibly need a double for loop but the complexity is making it difficult

This is what I have:

```
i = 0
locations = [23424977,2459115, 2487956]
onoff = [1,2]
for location in locations:
    for switch in onoff:
         i += 1
         if i < 4:
             trends1 = api.trends_place(location,include='hashtags')
         if i >=4:
             trends1 = api.trends_place(location,exclude='hashtags')
         print(trends1)
```

So I would want to end up with each `geo pull` having two sets of trending topics associated with it (those keywords with hashtags and those without).  However, this doesn't seem to be working as it is not looping through the locations.  NOTE: The issue is not overwriting of the variable (as the variable prints at the end of each loop) but instead with the ordering of the for loop.

EDIT
So in my head, the for loop should follow this progression:

```
Geo 1 - hashtag
Geo 2 - Hashtag
Geo 3 - Hashtag
Geo 1 - No hashtag
Geo 2 - No Hashtag
Geo 3 - No Hashtag
```

Comment: I suspect your bottleneck is from network latency. Why not make ONE request per geo, and then split it yourself later?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple and easy solution -- my original code had the order of the for loop reversed.  As the i variable is updated +1 at each iteration of the loop, the first three loops have hashtags since i<3 (since the "switch" loop is iterating through the first element and the location loop is iterating through the three geos), whereas after the third loop (where the "switch" for loop is now iterating through the second element and the location loop is iterating through the three geos) i>=4.

```
i = 0
locations = [23424977,2459115, 2487956]
onoff = [1,2]
for switch in onoff:
    for location in locations:

     i += 1
     if i < 4:
         trends1 = api.trends_place(location,include='hashtags')
     if i >=4:
         trends1 = api.trends_place(location,exclude='hashtags')
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need both the switch and i:

```
locations = [23424977,2459115, 2487956]
onoff = [1,2]
for switch in onoff:
    for location in locations:
        if onoff == 1:
             trends1 = api.trends_place(location,include='hashtags')
        else:
             trends1 = api.trends_place(location,exclude='hashtags')
        print(trends1)
```

Comment: The idea of the i was that the nested for loop should iterate a total of 6 times (3 geos X 2 hashtag states).  Each time the code runs through the loop, it is +1 to the i variable -- my logic was that on the first three loops of the geo include hashtags (i <= 3) and the next three loops don't include hashtags (i > 3)

Comment: This was a basic example but I save my output later -- the problem is that this for loop does not iterate through all of the geos

Comment: Your description is a little confusing to me, sorry. "i" is not being initialized in your solution, so I would do that and see if your results are better. Combine that with saving the results and not throwing them away like you are now, and maybe it will do what you want. Hopefully my code gets you closer.

Comment: It *does* iterate through the geos. You are throwing away the results for the earlier geos since you are over-writing the same variable every loop.

Comment: Overwriting is NOT the problem.  I am printing out the results after each loop.  I have edited the initial answer to include how I was hoping to set up my for loop

Comment: I can only evaluate the code you post. Not the code you don't. Thanks for the down-vote, sorry I tried to help at this point.

Comment: Upon further reflection I realize that my downvote of your question was in error.  You were addressing a problem that I did not have due to a poor explanation on my part and not yours (e.g. overwriting of data vs. the actual structure of the for loop).  I have cleaned up my question so it's clearer for those who have the same issue.  That being said, your answer may not be applicable based on the new question.  However,  please edit your answer so I can remove by downvote -- thank you.